# Navigation Issue with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, uitableview

How do I navigate back to the previous page with a UITableViewController. I tried to show a navigation bar with navigation button at the top of the screen, but the navigation bar will not show. I know that you have to give the previous view a title but when I go to do that it does not show anything. Also, since it is a UITableViewController I am not able to drop a navigation bar and add a button to the main view. All I would like to do is display my lists and have the option to navigate back to the previous list with a single button in the upper left corner.

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController. A hierarchy like this: UINavigationController > UITableViewController (your list) > UIViewController (or another UITableViewController with details). If so, you will automatically get the back button in the navigationBar.

Comment: No I am not. I have just been using the presentModalViewController in the UITableViewControllers to navigate forward.

Comment: You have two options. Whether use UINavigationController as @jonkroll suggested, or add a UIToolBar to the top or the bottom of your modalView, with a UIBarButtonItem, e.g. Close and link that to a method to dismiss the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you having with the NavigationController is that your tableViewController is not in the NavigationController hierarchy. Want you want to do this when adding the tableViewController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourTableViewController];
```

Then you can do this to add yourTableViewController:

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

If you don't want the navigationBar to appear on the tableViewController just use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

in yourTableViewController viewWillAppear method.

When your going to add the view after the tableView you just use:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: how do you get the yourTableViewController? Is it just self?

Comment: yourTableViewController would be wherever you created the TableViewController your talking about. So for example you have myFirstViewController, and when you press a button in myFirstViewController it adds the TableViewController to the screen. so you do something like UITableViewController *yourTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init]; What is the viewController right before the TableViewController that your using?

Comment: I never alloc a TableView all I do is create a new file that is a UITableViewController. I do not add one. I am inheriting UITableViewController instead of UIViewController. If that makes a difference even though I am starting to feel that it does.

Comment: How are you getting the tableView to display and is there anything that is displayed before it? or is the tableView your first screen?

Comment: The tableview is my first screen. I use the included methods that come with the UITableViewController when .m file is created. It automatically calls numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSectionsInTableView, and cellForRowAtIndexPath without me doing anything.

Comment: ok if the tableview is your first screen then it must be set in your appDelegate if you look in appDelegate.h does it have UITableViewController some where?

Comment: I miss understood what you meant. I have a viewController for my first screen in the app and that screen is a view controller which then goes to a UITableViewController and that is my only delegate. So would I have to create the navigation in the first screen and keep pushing it through. If it is that I am sorry for asking so much and will try that.

Comment: You don't really need to use the navigationController all the way thought. You just need to create it and use it to add the tableViewController and the viewController after. The thought behind that being your TableViewController will be Root. The back button was not appearing on your navigationBar because it was the Root. There was no back. It was the first view being added to the navigationController. So if you want the back button you need to make the TableViewController the first on the NavigationController.

Comment: This does not work. Thought it did but I can not get it to work. It is mostly because you are not allowed to do [self.view addSubview:navigationController];

Comment: Sorry its [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

Comment: You are fine I have been doing a lot wrong. I have found what I was missing and should be able to use your code segment now. Thank you for getting back to me

Comment: Worked perfectly after I redid the app with the navigation templet. I want people to up vote this because this was a lot of help. I will say one thing though that you may need to initWithNibName to create the controller and also a view controller needs to be added to the .xib that you're using with the specific .m file that you're trying to go from. That controller then needs to be linked to an IBOutlet that is made from the .m file you're going to. This mean @class is needed as well as an import. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to give the child view a title.  You need to give the child view's navigation item a title before you present it.  For example, in the parent view, before you push the the view to the navigation stack, do something like this...

```
[MyChildView.MyNavigationItem setTitle:@"A cool Title"];
```

Comment: Is MyChildView the name of the UITableViewController .m file so for instance I have a page called MealPlan. Before calling presentModalViewController I would do [MealPlan.MyNavigationItem setTitle...] Also is MyNavigationItem part of ios or is it something else I have to create. Sorry new to ios and missing some small idiosyncrasies. Or in this case a major one

Answer (score 0):

For the navigation you are trying to achieve you should be using a `UINavigationController`.  It already has the functionality you describe with the navigation bar and back button built into it.

To move to the next screen (which can be a UITableViewController) you use `pushViewController:animated:` and to move to the previous screen you use `popViewControllerAnimated:` (although the built in back button will do this for you).

I suggest reading the [UINavigationController class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you are not already familiar with it.

Comment: I will give that a try. Just wanted to double check. It says that it inherits from UIControllerView does UITableViewController inherit from UIControlView.

Comment: Yes UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController